# How to create a realistic jump in bge

Tags: game-engine

I'm  trying to create a FPS game in blender game engine. When I do *KeyBoard[Spacebar]* sensor and hook it up to a *simple motion* of *z +1* or something like that, the guys pops up really fast as if he didn't have any motion between being on the ground and being in the air. Is there a way to make a more realistic, more slow jump in BGE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the Linear velocity setting under simple motion. This will make your character's jump motion look much more realistic.

If you are using *Character* physics, you can simply use this setting.

[image]

You can change the settings for the character's jump speed and power in the Physics tab.

[image]

If you are using a dynamic object, or a rigid body object, you can use linear velocity along the z axis.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe a tad smaller on the download pic. your getting close...

Comment: Shrinking it...

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 2):

I use 
(these represent game logic)

```
Keypress-------and----------Motion (linv up)
if jump=0------/ \----------jump =30
if Ray-------/
```

if ray is positive, key is pressed and jump=0: Apply jump set jump property to 30

then

```
if jump min:2 max:30-----------and------------add -1 to jump

if jump=1 -----------and-----------jump=0
Ray positive---------/
```

**The advantage here is you can play a animation using the property jump,
and it will hold the last frame until you hit the ground,**

```
if jump changed -------and(order hack)-----------JumpProp =30-jump

if jump changed-----------and------------action Jump
```

**Also, you can use 'If jump==0" for other logic.**