# Jump actuator not working

Tags: game-engine

I am trying to create a game. My charaters other motions work like wasd stuff but jump doesnt work, yet it has the jump button shaded dark so please help

Comment: possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26960/how-to-create-a-realistic-jump-in-bge?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The "jump button shaded" suggests that you have selected "character motion", and clicked the "jump" option, but this doesn't mean your man jumps. All the "jump" button does is specifies the way the character moves.
Yours looks like this.

[image]

Needs to look like this. (see the *z.3?*)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set your physics type to "character", then you can easily controll jump height, step hight, ... in the physics-tab. Also you don't need to add a "z-movement" in the Motion-Actuator, this is all controlled by the Physics-Tab.[image]